# How to use bootstrap in blazor component library efficiently

Tags: blazor

I recently migrated my custom components from my blazor app to a blazor component library so that I could use them in other projects. The problem is that the blazor component library does not have bootstrap, thus when I pass class parameters from the app side, they do not function.

for instance :

```
<MyComponent Class="mt-5" />
```

In this case, there will be no top margin.

Of course, linking the bootstrap.min.css file to each component would work. I'm not a frontend developer and have little experience with this, so I'm wondering whether this would cause performance issues because the bootstrap file will be loaded for each component independently each time.

So my question is if this is a bad approach. If so, what are my alternatives?

Edit:

The component name is not actually MyComponent; I typed it down for convenience.

I'm actually adding some features on Mudblazor components..

```
<MudSelect Class="@class" />
```

where I define class as a string property

```
[Parameter]
public string Class { get; set; }
```

Comment: You only need to link `bootstrap.min.css` once in your project (inside `index.html` or `_Layout.cshtml`). The component library doesn't need to have bootstrap. Your component is probably not handling the `Class` parameter correctly. Can you show the implementation of `MyComponent`?

Comment: If you place this in your library you risk class name collisions with the consumer. If your library is "in house" that maybe ok.

Comment: I've updated the question accordingly @DimitrisMaragkos

Comment: I created a demo project with your scenario: https://github.com/Jimmys20/SO73770359. If you want you can take a look and tell me if you do something differently so I can reproduce your issue.